# How to prevent gridExtra::grid.arrage from automatically scaling the x axis in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, lubridate, gridextra

I run each of the below plots within the loop with no problem, but for some reason, when I try to combine them in grid.arrange the axes get scaled automatically. I can't figure out how to *not* automatically scale. I literally just want to combine the ggplots together (as if I used par(mfrow = c(2,3)) with base R).

I think the fact that the X axis is really a re-formatted datetime (as.posixct) is throwing it off. Ideally, I would like the X axis to display just the hour.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(bp)

df <- data(hypnos_data)

ids <- unique(df$ID)
id_tab <- cbind(ids, c(1:5))

index <- c(8:23, 0:7)

plot_list <- list()
for(i in ids){
  
  subs <- df[which(df$ID == i & df$VISIT == 1),]
  subs$DATE.TIME <- as.POSIXct(subs$DATE.TIME)
  subs$hour_rec <- lubridate::hour(subs$DATE.TIME)
  
  subs$hour_rec <- factor(subs$hour_rec, levels = as.character(index), ordered = T)
  
  row.names(subs) <- NULL
  
  tmp <- subs %>% dplyr::filter(WAKE == 0)
  min(tmp$hour_rec)
  
  p <- ggplot2::ggplot(subs, ggplot2::aes(x = DATE.TIME, y = SYST)) +
    
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = min(tmp$DATE.TIME), xmax = max(tmp$DATE.TIME), ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
              fill = "navajowhite2", alpha = 0.03) + 
    
    ggplot2::geom_point(aes(y = SYST), col = 'blue') + 
    ggplot2::geom_smooth(aes(y = SYST), method = "loess", col = 'blue') + 
    ggplot2::geom_point(aes(y = DIAST), col = 'red') + 
    ggplot2::geom_smooth(aes(y = DIAST), method = "loess", col = 'red') + 

    scale_x_datetime(date_label = "%H:%M", date_breaks = "1 hour") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45)) +
    
    ggtitle( paste("BP Profile for Subject: ", i, sep = "") )
  
  plot_list[[match(i, id_tab)]] <- p
  print(p)
  
  #grid::grid.newpage()
}
```

The above code should produce 5 plots similar to this (which are correct):

individual plot output

[image]

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = plot_list, ncol = 2 )
```

However, trying to combine them using grid.arrange yields the following:

grid.arrange plot output

[image]

Comment: Where are you viewing this? Did you try to expand the viewer?

Comment: This is in RStudio. I tried expanding it, but I couldn't make sense of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not in the `grid.arrange` It is due to the reference variable in `ggplot2`. Some of the axis data is reference values instead of stored values inside the plot. This result in the change in axis when the `subs` & `tmp` change for each `for-loop` interation. Here is a way to walk around it using `eval(substitute(...))`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(bp)
library(doParallel)
#> Loading required package: foreach
#> Loading required package: iterators
#> Loading required package: parallel

data(hypnos_data)
df <- hypnos_data
ids <- unique(df$ID)
id_tab <- cbind(ids, c(1:5))

index <- c(8:23, 0:7)

plot_list <- list()
plot_list <- foreach(i = ids) %do% {
  eval(substitute({
    subs <- df[which(df$ID == i & df$VISIT == 1),]
    subs$DATE.TIME <- as.POSIXct(subs$DATE.TIME)
    subs$hour_rec <- lubridate::hour(subs$DATE.TIME)
    
    subs$hour_rec <- factor(subs$hour_rec, levels = as.character(index), ordered = T)
    
    row.names(subs) <- NULL
    
    tmp <- subs %>% dplyr::filter(WAKE == 0)
    min(tmp$hour_rec)
    
    p <- ggplot2::ggplot(subs, ggplot2::aes(x = DATE.TIME, y = SYST)) +
      
      geom_rect(aes(xmin = min(tmp$DATE.TIME), xmax = max(tmp$DATE.TIME), ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
        fill = "navajowhite2", alpha = 0.03) + 
      ggplot2::geom_point(aes(y = SYST), col = 'blue') + 
      ggplot2::geom_smooth(aes(y = SYST), method = "loess", col = 'blue') + 
      ggplot2::geom_point(aes(y = DIAST), col = 'red') + 
      ggplot2::geom_smooth(aes(y = DIAST), method = "loess", col = 'red') + 
      
      scale_x_datetime(date_label = "%H:%M", date_breaks = "1 hour") +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45)) +
      
      ggtitle( paste("BP Profile for Subject: ", i, sep = "") )
  }, list(subs = as.name(paste0("subs_", i)), tmp = as.name(paste0("tmp_", i)))))
  
  p
}

gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = plot_list)
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image: Output plot]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>